# Remover elementos repetidos usando duas listas

Tags: python, lista

Como faria para remover sem usar `collections` e `while`, apenas com `for`. Queria uma estrutura de busca elemento a elemento, pois já sei remover dessa forma. Então quero usar no mínimo dois for encadeados.

```
for i in range(len(convidados)):
    pessoas.remove(convidados[i])
```

Tenho uma boa parte do código, funcionando. Na lista convidados, os elementos serão inseridos com `input()`, porém deixei assim para fins de praticidade.

```
pessoa= ["Matheus", "Maria", "Felipe", "Tulio", "Karen"]
convidados = ["Felipe","Karen","Matheus","Tulio"]
for i in range(len(pessoa)):
   # achei = 0
    #if 0 < i:
     #   i = 0
    for j in range(len(convidados)):
        if i > len(convidados) or i > len(pessoa):
        #pessoa.index(pessoa[i]):
            i -= 1
        elif pessoa[i] == convidados[j]:

            pessoa.remove(convidados[j])
            #j = achei
            #i=achei
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/443192/remover-elementos-repetidos-usando-duas-listas#comment853023_443193) você diz que quer remover da lista de pessoas todas as que foram convidadas. Então uma forma bem simples (assumindo que não há pessoas repetidas) é:

```
pessoas = ["Matheus", "Maria", "Felipe", "Tulio", "Karen"]
convidados = ["Felipe", "Karen", "Matheus", "Tulio"]

for convidado in convidados:
    try:
        pessoas.remove(convidado)
    except ValueError: # convidado não está na lista de pessoas
        pass

print(pessoas) # ['Maria']
```

Tomei o cuidado de capturar o [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError), pois caso o convidado não exista na lista de pessoas, esta exceção é lançada. No caso, estou ignorando o erro e indo para o próximo convidado (também mudei o nome da lista para `pessoas` - no plural - já que se trata de uma lista com várias pessoas; pode parecer um detalhe besta, mas [dar nomes melhores ajuda na hora de programar](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad)).

---

O problema é que `pessoas.remove(convidado)` só remove a primeira ocorrência do convidado, então **o código acima só funciona se a lista de pessoas não tiver nomes repetidos**. Por exemplo, se ela fosse:

```
pessoas = ["Matheus", "Maria", "Felipe", "Tulio", "Karen", "Felipe"]
```

Somente o primeiro "Felipe" seria removido, e o resultado seria `['Maria', 'Felipe']`.

Outro detalhe é que este código modifica a lista de pessoas. Se você não quer isso, uma alternativa é criar outra lista:

```
pessoas = ["Matheus", "Maria", "Felipe", "Tulio", "Karen", "Felipe", "Fulano", "Ciclano"]
convidados = ["Felipe", "Karen", "Matheus", "Tulio"]

pessoas_nao_convidadas = [ p for p in pessoas if p not in convidados ]
print(pessoas_nao_convidadas) # ['Maria', 'Fulano', 'Ciclano']
```

Neste caso, além de criar outra lista, eu também eliminei as repetições, verificando se a pessoa não está na lista de convidados com `not in`.

---

Se manter a ordem das pessoas **não** for importante, você também pode usar [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-set), que é uma estrutura que não permite elementos repetidos. Assim, basta tranformar as listas em `set`'s, subtrair um do outro e converter o resultado em uma lista:

```
pessoas = ["Matheus", "Maria", "Felipe", "Tulio", "Karen", "Felipe", "Fulano", "Ciclano"]
convidados = ["Felipe", "Karen", "Matheus", "Tulio"]

# retorna uma lista com 'Maria', 'Fulano' e 'Ciclano', mas não necessariamente nesta ordem
pessoas_nao_convidadas =  list(set(pessoas) - set(convidados))
```

---

> *Então quero usar no mínimo dois for encadeados*

Para que? Não precisa, as soluções acima são bem mais simples, o seu código estava complicando à toa.

<sup>*Tudo bem que a solução com `not in` deve fazer uma busca linear na lista, então é um "loop implícito" dentro de um `for`, mas a questão é que **você** não precisa usar dois `for` explícitos encadeados.*</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Olá,

Você pode criar uma nova lista que irá conter os elementos não repetidos:

```
arraySemRepeticao = [] # Lista que terá os elementos não repetidos
convidados = ["Felipe", "Karen", "Matheus", "Tulio"]
pessoa = ["Matheus", "Maria", "Felipe", "Tulio", "Karen"]

todos = convidados + pessoa    # Concatena as duas listas

for i in range(len(todos)):    # Irá percorrer a lista que contém elementos repetidos
    if not todos[i] in arraySemRepeticao:    # Irá verificar se elemento não existe, e se não existir, ele entra nesse if
        arraySemRepeticao.append(todos[i])    # Adiciona no fim da lista o elemento que não existe ainda

print(arraySemRepeticao)
```

Se essa não for a solução que busca, você ainda pode se basear em uma nova solução com a mesma lógica dessa: eu crio um array novo somente com os elementos que ainda não existem, ou seja, se existir, ele não adiciona.

Fiz uma método que funcionaria com infinitas listas e que não cria uma nova lista:

```
def flat(*list):
    newList = []

    for i in range(len(list)):
        for j in range(len(list[i])):
            newList.append(list[i][j])

    return newList


def removeDuplicates(*list):
    flattedList = flat(*list)
    newList = []

    for i in range(len(flattedList)):
        if not flattedList[i] in newList:
            newList.append(flattedList[i])

    return newList


print(removeDuplicates([1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1], [4, 2, 1])) # [1, 2, 3, 4]

pessoa = ["Matheus", "Maria", "Felipe", "Tulio", "Karen"]
convidados = ["Felipe", "Karen", "Matheus", "Tulio"]

print(removeDuplicates(pessoa, convidados)) # ['Matheus', 'Maria', 'Felipe', 'Tulio', 'Karen']
```

Para remover todos elementos de `pessoa` que estão em `convidados`, faça o seguinte código:

```
pessoa = ["Matheus", "Maria", "Felipe", "Tulio", "Karen"]
convidados = ["Felipe", "Karen", "Matheus", "Tulio"]

for i in range(len(pessoa)):
    if pessoa[i] in convidados:
        pessoa[i] = None

pessoa = [x for x in pessoa if x is not None] # Remove todos os None
print(pessoa)
```

Comment: Sim é uma solução, uma das formas que tbm não quis usar é uma nova lista.

Comment: Editei e postei uma nova solução, veja se te atende...

Comment: Deve ser removido da lista pessoa as pessoas que foram convidadas, deve ser resultada as duas listas, mostrando a lista pessoa sem os convidados escolhidos. Meu código consegue remover mas não tem  uma condição de parada.

Comment: Entendi, editei novamente com uma nova solução, veja se te atende :)

Comment: Entendo é que eu gostaria muito de seguir a mesma estrutura mantendo o código, eu até consegui remover quando há mais de 1 pessoa, porém eu gostaria de que algo fizesse o índice voltar a 0, dessa forma eu consigo remover quem sobrou.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, eu por conta do tempo desenvolvi uma forma bem complicada de conseguir que com dois for's seja possível, eu propus dessa forma para fins de lógica, e alcançar o resultado sem mudar muito a estrutura, gostei bastante da solução de hktsubo principalmente, chega muito próximo do que eu queria. Aqui está o que eu pude fazer sem fugir da estrutura dos fors:

```
pessoa= ["Matheus", "Maria", "Felipe", "Tulio", "Karen","belinhaAlmeida"]
convidados = ["Matheus", "Maria", "Tulio", "Karen"]
cont = 0
for i in range(len(pessoa)):

   # achei = 0
    #if 0 < i:
     #   i = 0
    for j in range(len(convidados)):
        if i > len(convidados) or i > len(pessoa)-1:
            i -= 1
       # elif i > pessoa.index(pessoa[j]):
        #    i -= 1
        if len(pessoa) == 1:
            break
                #cont -= 1
        if cont > len(pessoa)-1:
                cont -= 1
        elif pessoa[cont] == convidados[j]:



            pessoa.remove(convidados[j])
            cont = 0
            #j = achei
            #i=achei
    cont += 1
print(pessoa)
```

Remove qualquer pessoa acredito eu.